# feature extraction for classification matlab

Tags: matlab, svm, feature-extraction

I have a feature matrix 977x3

```
features = rand(977,3);
```

where each row is an observation and each column is a feature.

I calculate the pairwise distances between point with

```
dissimilarities = pdist(features);
```

and then I scale it with

```
feature_transf = mdscale(dissimilarities,3);
```

I use the new set of features (feature_transf) for classification.

Does it have any sense? I have good classification accuracy training a SVM with 10 fold cross validation.

Can you please tell me if it is methodologically incorrect?

Thanks,
Gabriele

Comment: I don't know much about mdscale, but apparently it is supposed to help more with visualization aspects of the data clouds. Also, you never mentioned any labels or function values so I'm kind of confused. Finally, is there a way of going back from the scaled distance space to the original 3-D space of your problem? If not, maybe all you want is to run SVM on your feature matrix directly.